# Index out of range error while training dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I am trying to train MaskRCNN to detect and segment apples using the dataset from this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.06441),

[github link to code being used](https://github.com/nicolaihaeni/MinneApple.git)

I am simply following the instructions as provided in the ReadMe file..

Here is the output on console

```
(venv) PS > python train_rcnn.py --data_path 'D:\Research Report\tensorflow\Mask_RCNN-TRIALS\Mask_RCNN-master\datasets\apples-minneapple' --model mrcnn --epochs 50 --output-dir 'D:\Research Report\tensorflow\Mask_RCNN-TRIALS\Mask_RCNN-master\samples\apples'

mrcnn
Namespace(batch_size=2, data_path='D:\\Research Report\\tensorflow\\Mask_RCNN-TRIALS\\Mask_RCNN-master\\datasets\\apples-minneapple', dataset='AppleDataset', device='cuda', epochs=50, lr=0.02, lr_gamma=0.1, lr_step_size=8, lr_steps=[8, 11], model='mrcnn', momentum=0.9, output_dir='D:\\Research Report\\tensorflow\\Mask_RCNN-TRIALS\\Mask_RCNN-master\\samples\\apples', print_freq=20, resume='', weight_decay=0.0001, workers=4)
Loading data
Creating data loaders
Creating model
Start training
Epoch: [0]  [  0/335]  eta: 1:00:28  lr: 0.000080  loss: 2.4100 (2.4100)  loss_classifier: 0.8481 (0.8481)  loss_box_reg: 0.4164 (0.4164)  loss_objectness: 0.9299 (0.9299)  loss_rpn_box_reg: 0.2157 (0.2157)  time: 10.8327  data: 7.9925  max mem: 2733
Epoch: [0]  [ 20/335]  eta: 0:06:18  lr: 0.001276  loss: 1.4465 (1.4728)  loss_classifier: 0.5526 (0.5496)  loss_box_reg: 0.3586 (0.3572)  loss_objectness: 0.2666 (0.3418)  loss_rpn_box_reg: 0.2233 (0.2242)  time: 0.7204  data: 0.0132  max mem: 3247
Epoch: [0]  [ 40/335]  eta: 0:04:48  lr: 0.002473  loss: 0.9622 (1.2287)  loss_classifier: 0.2927 (0.4276)  loss_box_reg: 0.3188 (0.3314)  loss_objectness: 0.1422 (0.2491)  loss_rpn_box_reg: 0.2168 (0.2207)  time: 0.7408  data: 0.0210  max mem: 3282
Epoch: [0]  [ 60/335]  eta: 0:04:05  lr: 0.003669  loss: 0.7924 (1.0887)  loss_classifier: 0.2435 (0.3654)  loss_box_reg: 0.2361 (0.2983)  loss_objectness: 0.1289 (0.2105)  loss_rpn_box_reg: 0.1898 (0.2144)  time: 0.7244  data: 0.0127  max mem: 3432
Epoch: [0]  [ 80/335]  eta: 0:03:37  lr: 0.004865  loss: 0.7438 (1.0117)  loss_classifier: 0.2565 (0.3376)  loss_box_reg: 0.2193 (0.2799)  loss_objectness: 0.0776 (0.1835)  loss_rpn_box_reg: 0.1983 (0.2108)  time: 0.7217  data: 0.0127  max mem: 3432
Epoch: [0]  [100/335]  eta: 0:03:14  lr: 0.006062  loss: 0.7373 (0.9490)  loss_classifier: 0.2274 (0.3156)  loss_box_reg: 0.2193 (0.2654)  loss_objectness: 0.0757 (0.1643)  loss_rpn_box_reg: 0.1867 (0.2037)  time: 0.7291  data: 0.0132  max mem: 3432
Epoch: [0]  [120/335]  eta: 0:02:54  lr: 0.007258  loss: 0.8275 (0.9243)  loss_classifier: 0.2689 (0.3094)  loss_box_reg: 0.2315 (0.2602)  loss_objectness: 0.0867 (0.1539)  loss_rpn_box_reg: 0.1883 (0.2008)  time: 0.7270  data: 0.0134  max mem: 3432
Epoch: [0]  [140/335]  eta: 0:02:35  lr: 0.008455  loss: 0.7886 (0.9057)  loss_classifier: 0.2573 (0.3029)  loss_box_reg: 0.2246 (0.2539)  loss_objectness: 0.0724 (0.1455)  loss_rpn_box_reg: 0.2459 (0.2035)  time: 0.7170  data: 0.0124  max mem: 3432
Epoch: [0]  [160/335]  eta: 0:02:17  lr: 0.009651  loss: 0.7588 (0.8878)  loss_classifier: 0.2341 (0.2948)  loss_box_reg: 0.2226 (0.2486)  loss_objectness: 0.1032 (0.1427)  loss_rpn_box_reg: 0.2020 (0.2016)  time: 0.7139  data: 0.0118  max mem: 3432
Epoch: [0]  [180/335]  eta: 0:02:01  lr: 0.010847  loss: 0.7340 (0.8744)  loss_classifier: 0.2331 (0.2898)  loss_box_reg: 0.2120 (0.2441)  loss_objectness: 0.1086 (0.1392)  loss_rpn_box_reg: 0.1993 (0.2012)  time: 0.7800  data: 0.0584  max mem: 3432
Epoch: [0]  [200/335]  eta: 0:01:45  lr: 0.012044  loss: 0.8106 (0.8694)  loss_classifier: 0.2616 (0.2873)  loss_box_reg: 0.2208 (0.2411)  loss_objectness: 0.1117 (0.1397)  loss_rpn_box_reg: 0.1927 (0.2014)  time: 0.7344  data: 0.0143  max mem: 3432
Epoch: [0]  [220/335]  eta: 0:01:29  lr: 0.013240  loss: 0.8191 (0.8610)  loss_classifier: 0.2581 (0.2848)  loss_box_reg: 0.2140 (0.2382)  loss_objectness: 0.0860 (0.1362)  loss_rpn_box_reg: 0.2177 (0.2018)  time: 0.7213  data: 0.0126  max mem: 3432
Epoch: [0]  [240/335]  eta: 0:01:13  lr: 0.014437  loss: 0.7890 (0.8590)  loss_classifier: 0.2671 (0.2842)  loss_box_reg: 0.2094 (0.2357)  loss_objectness: 0.1175 (0.1360)  loss_rpn_box_reg: 0.2256 (0.2030)  time: 0.7576  data: 0.0564  max mem: 3432
Epoch: [0]  [260/335]  eta: 0:00:57  lr: 0.015633  loss: 0.8631 (0.8587)  loss_classifier: 0.2900 (0.2849)  loss_box_reg: 0.2089 (0.2337)  loss_objectness: 0.0925 (0.1350)  loss_rpn_box_reg: 0.2271 (0.2050)  time: 0.7371  data: 0.0220  max mem: 3432
Epoch: [0]  [280/335]  eta: 0:00:42  lr: 0.016830  loss: 0.8464 (0.8580)  loss_classifier: 0.2679 (0.2840)  loss_box_reg: 0.2156 (0.2321)  loss_objectness: 0.0940 (0.1346)  loss_rpn_box_reg: 0.2345 (0.2073)  time: 0.7379  data: 0.0143  max mem: 3432
Epoch: [0]  [300/335]  eta: 0:00:27  lr: 0.018026  loss: 0.7991 (0.8519)  loss_classifier: 0.2485 (0.2819)  loss_box_reg: 0.2125 (0.2305)  loss_objectness: 0.0819 (0.1315)  loss_rpn_box_reg: 0.2217 (0.2080)  time: 0.8549  data: 0.1419  max mem: 3450
Epoch: [0]  [320/335]  eta: 0:00:11  lr: 0.019222  loss: 0.6906 (0.8432)  loss_classifier: 0.2362 (0.2791)  loss_box_reg: 0.2036 (0.2285)  loss_objectness: 0.0662 (0.1285)  loss_rpn_box_reg: 0.1801 (0.2070)  time: 0.7257  data: 0.0238  max mem: 3450
Epoch: [0]  [334/335]  eta: 0:00:00  lr: 0.020000  loss: 0.7822 (0.8441)  loss_classifier: 0.2501 (0.2785)  loss_box_reg: 0.2224 (0.2285)  loss_objectness: 0.1135 (0.1296)  loss_rpn_box_reg: 0.1948 (0.2075)  time: 0.7249  data: 0.0139  max mem: 3450
Epoch: [0] Total time: 0:04:18 (0.7707 s / it)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train_rcnn.py", line 143, in <module>
    main(args)
  File "train_rcnn.py", line 109, in main
    evaluate(model, data_loader_test, device=device)
  File "C:\Users\___\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\torch\autograd\grad_mode.py", line 49, in decorate_no_grad
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Research Report\tensorflow\Mask_RCNN-TRIALS\Mask_RCNN-master\samples\apples\utility\engine.py", line 78, in evaluate
    coco = get_coco_api_from_dataset(data_loader.dataset)
  File "D:\Research Report\tensorflow\Mask_RCNN-TRIALS\Mask_RCNN-master\samples\apples\utility\coco_utils.py", line 205, in get_coco_api_from_dataset
    return convert_to_coco_api(dataset)
  File "D:\Research Report\tensorflow\Mask_RCNN-TRIALS\Mask_RCNN-master\samples\apples\utility\coco_utils.py", line 154, in convert_to_coco_api
    img, targets = ds[img_idx]
  File "D:\Research Report\tensorflow\Mask_RCNN-TRIALS\Mask_RCNN-master\samples\apples\data\apple_dataset.py", line 22, in __getitem__
    mask_path = os.path.join(self.root_dir, "masks", self.masks[idx])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

This is the file that is run in order to train the network

```
import datetime
import os
import time

import torch
import torch.utils.data
import torchvision
from torchvision.models.detection.faster_rcnn import FastRCNNPredictor
from torchvision.models.detection.mask_rcnn import MaskRCNNPredictor

from data.apple_dataset import AppleDataset
from utility.engine import train_one_epoch, evaluate

import utility.utils as utils
import utility.transforms as T

######################################################
# Train either a Faster-RCNN or Mask-RCNN predictor
# using the MinneApple dataset
######################################################


def get_transform(train):
    transforms = []
    transforms.append(T.ToTensor())
    if train:
        transforms.append(T.RandomHorizontalFlip(0.5))
    return T.Compose(transforms)


def get_maskrcnn_model_instance(num_classes):
    # load an instance segmentation model pre-trained pre-trained on COCO
    model = torchvision.models.detection.maskrcnn_resnet50_fpn(pretrained=True)

    # get number of input features for the classifier
    in_features = model.roi_heads.box_predictor.cls_score.in_features
    # replace the pre-trained head with a new one
    model.roi_heads.box_predictor = FastRCNNPredictor(in_features, num_classes)

    # now get the number of input features for the mask classifier
    in_features_mask = model.roi_heads.mask_predictor.conv5_mask.in_channels
    hidden_layer = 256
    # and replace the mask predictor with a new one
    model.roi_heads.mask_predictor = MaskRCNNPredictor(in_features_mask, hidden_layer, num_classes)
    return model


def get_frcnn_model_instance(num_classes):
    # load an instance segmentation model pre-trained pre-trained on COCO
    model = torchvision.models.detection.fasterrcnn_resnet50_fpn(pretrained=True)

    # get number of input features for the classifier
    in_features = model.roi_heads.box_predictor.cls_score.in_features
    # replace the pre-trained head with a new one
    model.roi_heads.box_predictor = FastRCNNPredictor(in_features, num_classes)
    return model


def main(args):
    print(args)
    device = args.device

    # Data loading code
    print("Loading data")
    num_classes = 2
    dataset = AppleDataset(os.path.join(args.data_path, 'train'), get_transform(train=True))
    dataset_test = AppleDataset(os.path.join(args.data_path, 'test'), get_transform(train=False))

    print("Creating data loaders")
    data_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=args.batch_size, shuffle=True,
                                              num_workers=args.workers, collate_fn=utils.collate_fn)

    data_loader_test = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset_test, batch_size=1,
                                                   shuffle=False, num_workers=args.workers,
                                                   collate_fn=utils.collate_fn)

    print("Creating model")
    # Create the correct model type
    if args.model == 'maskrcnn':
        model = get_maskrcnn_model_instance(num_classes)
    else:
        model = get_frcnn_model_instance(num_classes)

    # Move model to the right device
    model.to(device)

    params = [p for p in model.parameters() if p.requires_grad]
    optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(params, lr=args.lr, momentum=args.momentum, weight_decay=args.weight_decay)

    #  lr_scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimizer, step_size=args.lr_step_size, gamma=args.lr_gamma)
    lr_scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.MultiStepLR(optimizer, milestones=args.lr_steps, gamma=args.lr_gamma)

    if args.resume:
        checkpoint = torch.load(args.resume, map_location='cpu')
        model.load_state_dict(checkpoint['model'])
        optimizer.load_state_dict(checkpoint['optimizer'])
        lr_scheduler.load_state_dict(checkpoint['lr_scheduler'])

    print("Start training")
    start_time = time.time()
    for epoch in range(args.epochs):
        train_one_epoch(model, optimizer, data_loader, device, epoch, args.print_freq)
        lr_scheduler.step()

        if args.output_dir:
            torch.save(model.state_dict(), os.path.join(args.output_dir, 'model_{}.pth'.format(epoch)))

        # evaluate after every epoch
        evaluate(model, data_loader_test, device=device)

    total_time = time.time() - start_time
    total_time_str = str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=int(total_time)))
    print('Training time {}'.format(total_time_str))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import argparse
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='PyTorch Detection Training')
    parser.add_argument('--data_path', default='~~~~', help='dataset')
    parser.add_argument('--dataset', default='AppleDataset', help='dataset')
    parser.add_argument('--model', default='maskrcnn', help='model')
    parser.add_argument('--device', default='cuda', help='device')
    parser.add_argument('-b', '--batch-size', default=2, type=int)
    parser.add_argument('--epochs', default=13, type=int, metavar='N', help='number of total epochs to run')
    parser.add_argument('-j', '--workers', default=4, type=int, metavar='N', help='number of data loading workers (default: 16)')
    parser.add_argument('--lr', default=0.02, type=float, help='initial learning rate')
    parser.add_argument('--momentum', default=0.9, type=float, metavar='M', help='momentum')
    parser.add_argument('--wd', '--weight-decay', default=1e-4, type=float, metavar='W', help='weight decay (default: 1e-4)', dest='weight_decay')
    parser.add_argument('--lr-step-size', default=8, type=int, help='decrease lr every step-size epochs')
    parser.add_argument('--lr-steps', default=[8, 11], nargs='+', type=int, help='decrease lr every step-size epochs')
    parser.add_argument('--lr-gamma', default=0.1, type=float, help='decrease lr by a factor of lr-gamma')
    parser.add_argument('--print-freq', default=20, type=int, help='print frequency')
    parser.add_argument('--output-dir', default='.', help='path where to save')
    parser.add_argument('--resume', default='', help='resume from checkpoint')

    args = parser.parse_args()
    print(args.model)
    assert(args.model in ['mrcnn', 'frcnn'])

    if args.output_dir:
        utils.mkdir(args.output_dir)

    main(args)
```

Apple_dataset.py is as follows

```
import os
import numpy as np
import torch
from PIL import Image

#####################################
# Class that takes the input instance masks
# and extracts bounding boxes on the fly
#####################################
class AppleDataset(object):
    def __init__(self, root_dir, transforms):
        self.root_dir = root_dir
        self.transforms = transforms

        # Load all image and mask files, sorting them to ensure they are aligned
        self.imgs = list(sorted(os.listdir(os.path.join(root_dir, "images"))))
        self.masks = list(sorted(os.listdir(os.path.join(root_dir, "masks"))))

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        # Load images and masks
        img_path = os.path.join(self.root_dir, "images", self.imgs[idx])
        mask_path = os.path.join(self.root_dir, "masks", self.masks[idx])

        img = Image.open(img_path).convert("RGB")
        mask = Image.open(mask_path)     # Each color of mask corresponds to a different instance with 0 being the background

        # Convert the PIL image to np array
        mask = np.array(mask)
        obj_ids = np.unique(mask)

        # Remove background id
        obj_ids = obj_ids[1:]

        # Split the color-encoded masks into a set of binary masks
        masks = mask == obj_ids[:, None, None]

        # Get bbox coordinates for each mask
        num_objs = len(obj_ids)
        boxes = []
        h, w = mask.shape
        for ii in range(num_objs):
            pos = np.where(masks[ii])
            xmin = np.min(pos[1])
            xmax = np.max(pos[1])
            ymin = np.min(pos[0])
            ymax = np.max(pos[0])

            if xmin == xmax or ymin == ymax:
                continue

            xmin = np.clip(xmin, a_min=0, a_max=w)
            xmax = np.clip(xmax, a_min=0, a_max=w)
            ymin = np.clip(ymin, a_min=0, a_max=h)
            ymax = np.clip(ymax, a_min=0, a_max=h)
            boxes.append([xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax])

        # Convert everything into a torch.Tensor
        boxes = torch.as_tensor(boxes, dtype=torch.float32)

        # There is only one class (apples)
        labels = torch.ones((num_objs,), dtype=torch.int64)
        masks = torch.as_tensor(masks, dtype=torch.uint8)

        image_id = torch.tensor([idx])
        area = (boxes[:, 3] - boxes[:, 1]) * (boxes[:, 2] - boxes[:, 0])

        # All instances are not crowd
        iscrowd = torch.zeros((num_objs,), dtype=torch.int64)

        target = {}
        target["boxes"] = boxes
        target["labels"] = labels
        target["masks"] = masks
        target["image_id"] = image_id
        target["area"] = area
        target["iscrowd"] = iscrowd

        if self.transforms is not None:
            img, target = self.transforms(img, target)

        return img, target

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.imgs)

    def get_img_name(self, idx):
        return self.imgs[idx]
```

How do i fix the index going out of range??? OR what is the underlying issue that needs to be addressed here??

EDIT1: ok.. so whats happening here is i have two folders "train" and "test".. the training folder has the images and masks, while test folder has only images.. the apple_dataset.py is written such that its looking for masks folder in both train and test folders.. i think i need to change the code such that it looks for masks in only the train folder and not the test set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed this by creating a dummy folder called 'masks' in the "test" folder.. just copy paste the one from 'train' with all the masks.. the train and predict scripts wont really use it, so shoudnt be any issues here..

also look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60795375/unable-to-load-model-weights-while-predicting-using-pytorch) issue for more changes that need to be made

Answer (score 0):

Error is telling every thing you are trying to access an index from list self.masks which does not exist
issue is in this line `mask_path = os.path.join(self.root_dir, "masks", self.masks[idx])`. You need to check the value of idx every time it is being passed only then you can figure out the problem

Comment: ok.. so whats happening here is i have two folders "train" and "test".. the training folder has the images and masks, while test folder has only images.. the apple_dataset.py is written such that its looking for masks folder in both train and test folders.. i think i need to change the code such that it looks for masks in only the train folder and not the test set